# Excel VBA Copy Paste Values only( xlPasteValues ) on same columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code

```
    Sheets("Main").Columns("H:S").Copy
    Sheets("Main").Columns("H:S").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

It is not working, but manually works very well. What is problem?

Runtime error 1004
Says what copy size differs from paste size

Recorded macro also got same error on repeat, there are no merged cells and filters, no hidden rows and  columns

Comment: Are there merged cells?

Comment: Or hidden rows, columns (i.e. autofilter)?

Comment: Humor me and try `Sheets("Main").Columns("H:S").Cells(1,1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: Or try  `Sheets("Main").Columns("H:S").Value = Sheets("Main").Columns("H:S").Value` ... But if merged cells are there, nothing will work until you get rid of the merged cells. (well there is a way around, but, it's inefficient). Also, you are tying up a *ton* of resources by copying the entire column range. Is there a reason for this? You may be better served just copying the rows of the columns that have data.

Comment: but manually works very well ?!?!? Recorder your manual operation and see the code generated

Comment: The code is fine, mechanically. It's probably one of the above hidden or merged cells. Both the above suggestions work as well.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman Your variant work but takes to much times

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - see the part in my comment about using the whole`EntireColumn` range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approach...

`With Sheets("Main").Columns("H:S")
      .Value = .Value
End With`